# select elements ajax automaticly after call

Tags: ajax, jquery

My question is, how is possible select or manipulate the elements take from a call ajax without every time put the `.on/.live` method of jquery? 
there is another way more fast?

Comment: Can you show us what your current code looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the elements are not inside the DOM when DOM is ready, you have to do such delegation

like

```
.on()
```